# OpenGL: What happens if I specify a light as both specular and diffuse?

Tags: opengl, lighting

On the sphere lighting example of the redbook I read this:

```
GLfloat light_ambient[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 };
GLfloat light_diffuse[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
GLfloat light_specular[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
GLfloat light_position[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0 };

glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, light_ambient);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, light_diffuse);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, light_specular);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position);
```

Then it says:

> In this example, the first three calls
>   to glLightfv() are superfluous, since
>   they’re being used to specify the
>   default values for the GL_AMBIENT,
>   GL_DIFFUSE, and GL_SPECULAR parameter

As I understand so far, every light source has default values for its ambient, diffuse and specular parameters and these three arrays specify what are those default values, **is that right?**  **Does every light source is by default diffuse, specular and ambient?**

Comment: BTW- redbook is kind of old, you can use it by source of theory but it's good not to use it as an OpenGL tutorial. Nowadays the best and easiest way to handle lighting (among other things) is to use shaders, which is what you should dive into ASAP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the OpenGL lighting model, 4 separate lighting equations are computed for an object: Ambient, Diffuse, Specular, and Emission.  Ambient doesn't take the normals into account, Diffuse and Specular do, and Emission doesn't take light into account at all.

All these different lighting values are summed to give the final color of an object.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, these are the default values for Light0: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glLight.xml

Comment: +1. Also note that's is a good practice not to rely on the default values.

Comment: @kos: Very true - if you want reproducibel results you should always specify these things explicitly.